# I need to know if I need a privacy policy for a computer app

Tags: privacy, software, data-ownership

make computer apps using Winforms and such the apps that i make are computer side only nothing gets stored off the computer nothing gets moved anywhere else lets say i have an app that needs your email and it just saves it inside the app itself after the user enters it without ever leaving or sending that information anywhere but in the computer itself would this require a privacy policy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why would you *need* an email address, when it never leaves that computer?

Comment: I was just writing a similar thought to nvoigt. Saving could be considered processing, but if it doesn't do anything else with it, why save it?

Comment: for the bot i dont know how to clarify it more i need to know if i need a privacy policy and for the other people sorry if there was any miscommunication the information the email info never leaves the computer but the application in question would have the ability to send stuff using an email the users email so you can send a email using it to do so it would need the users email info the info never gets moved off of the computer and is saved only in the app after the user chooses to

Comment: @Zerium4 - The bot has probably been triggered as there's no punctuation or grammar. It's worth a rewrite, but if you're talking about a mailing list controlled by or through software there are significant legal implications - many of them jurisdiction based, which is likely to be the multiple jurisdictions of any users. If you're talking about offering the app through Microsoft it would probably not get past their approval process as it stands, but if it did it would be worth getting a professional legal opinion to cover your back - Microsoft are more interested in covering their own.

Answer (score 2):

So your privacy rules are "nothing ever leaves the computer, and the only private information stored is the user's email address which is stored inside the application". So that's what goes into your privacy policy.

Normally a privacy policy would be viewable on your website, but you can also just add a menu item "View Privacy Policy" into your application, where you display the privacy policy.

As others mentioned in comments, what exactly is going on with that email address? If it isn't used, why is it stored? So I suppose you use it somehow. Put that into your privacy policy. "Your email address is recorded so you can receive an email when a new version of the application becomes available", just as an example what could go into your privacy policy. If that's your only use obviously.